# How to replace URLSearchParams and get full URL after modification

Tags: javascript

In this situation:

```
let url = new URL(link.url);
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
params.append("collection", this.collection);
```

I can call `params.toString()` to get the final search params. How best can I get the full URL?

```
console.log(url)
```

Gets me:

```
hash: ""
host: "stackoverflow.dev"
hostname: "stackoverflow.dev"
href: "http://stackoverflow.dev/media?page=2"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.dev"
password: ""
pathname: "/media"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
search: "?page=2"
searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
username: ""
```

Is it recommended to manually rebuild the URL, i.e:

```
[url.origin, url.pathname, '?', params.toString()].join('');
```

Or is there an inbuilt function for applying the updated search params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [url.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) property to `set` or `append` a query string in an existing [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) instance.

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.sample.com?a=1');

url.searchParams.append('b', '2');

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, I think I was needlessly adding a step.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this function

```
const buildParams = (filters) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams()
  Object.entries(filters).forEach(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(filterValue)) {
      params.append(filterName, filterValue.join(','))
    } else if (filterValue) {
      params.append(filterName, filterValue)
    }
  })
  return params.toString()
}
```

Of course could be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Try `url.origin + url.pathname + "?" + params.toString()` (as you said) to use it for the same URL as the document. It logs the location of the document, then a "?" and then the search params. If you want to see it for an external URL, then use `url.origin + url.pathname + "?" + url.search.substring(1) + "&" + params.toString();`.

But you can also use `url.searchParams.append()` instead of making a new params variable. Every URL object contains a URLSearchParams object.